# JQuery trigger change even of combo box the selected value checked on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox, hide, onload

I've a combo box (select option) with values `yes` and `no` which are coming from the database if value is yes then `<div id="someid">` should display true (show) if value is no then `<div id="someid">` should hide. I'm trying through the following code.

```
$(function(){
    if($('#yesnocombo').selectedIndex == 1){
        $('#someid').show();
    }else{
        $('#someid').hide();
    }
});
```

How can I trigger event automatically depending on the selected value of the combobox?

Any Idea?

Comment: that is not the issue i just typed that off for this forum this is not the actual code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will trigger on page load, but *will not trigger on a change event*:

```
if($('#yesnocombo > option:selected').index() == 0){
    $('#someid').show();
}else{
    $('#someid').hide();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Fjbt7/

Comment: Thank you very much @Jay Blanchard, you're a legend... thanks one more time :)

Answer (score 1):

you need to write [**change()**](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event for drop down:

## HTML:

```
<select id="yesnocombo">
    <option value="yes">yes</option>
    <option value="no">no</option>
</select>
<div id="someid">Some text</div>
```

## JQUERY:

```
$(function () {
    $('#yesnocombo').change(function () {

        if ($(this).val() === "yes") {
            $('#someid').show();
        } else {
            $('#someid').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

for programmatically tirggering you can write:

```
$("#yesnocombo").trigger("change");
```

## FIDDLE:

[**FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/XSmWU/2/)

Comment: i know i but that will only on click i think you havent read question properly

Comment: you can trigger like this: ``$("#yesnocombo").trigger("change");``

Comment: this is not what i want please dont waste time on this i need to make a decision on page load what value is coming from db yes or no

Comment: @UsmanSharifAmjadKhan this line you wrote in last commentu should have written in question in cleat words, now you are clearing in simple words, always try to write question in simple words

Comment: thank you very much for your effort @Ehsan Sajjad my mistake I'm sorry